# Do I need more nested levels to read a simple ( almost flat ) FireBase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have set up a fairly complex relationship between different side loaded iOS apps and web tech for different folk at a farming company to track various important things in their crops.

It all works happily except one thing is making a mockery of my experience ( or I don't know how to sleuth Firebase docs ). The following .js code only lists the last entry entered under a miscellaneous collection called 'OPnotes'. (There is another property with OFnotes).

a representation of the data I'm trying to display to web is thus:

```
 |
OPnotes
 |   + -- OF-Ave-g9: "OF-Ave g9 &nbsp; ant nest"
 |   + -- OPA-2A-j5: "OPA-2A j5 &nbsp; excessive sap"
 |   + -- OPA-SR-k2: "OPA-SR k2 &nbsp; irrigation leak"
 |
```

I've commented out the childkey variable because I can't get it to do anything. I would have thought of the `snapshot.forEach(` would be responsible for doing the iterating.

```
<script>
    var noteRef = firebase.database().ref('OPnotes');

    noteRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
        // this next line should set up iterations of each child
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {

            // var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
            var note = childSnapshot.val();
            document.getElementById("sh owNote").innerHTML = note;

         });
    });
</script>
```

I'm keeping everything human-readable as I put together enough different data from GPS readings and crop designations to make unique keys for various staff to locate the issues in their minds, which is why part of the keys are repeated in the visible text. I don't think that's the issue here.

Basically the question is do I really need to make a more complex schema to read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `snapshot.forEach` indeed loops over each child node in the result. But then you do `document.getElementById("sh owNote").innerHTML = note`, which means that each time you **overwrite** whatever was in the HTML element before that. So at the end of the loop, you end up with just the value of the last node in the HTML.

What you're probably looking for is something closer to:

```
noteRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    document.getElementById("sh owNote").innerHTML += "";
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        var note = childSnapshot.val();
        document.getElementById("sh owNote").innerHTML += note + "<br/>";
     });
});
```

Comment: thanks Frank, I suspected (overnight) something like that would be happening and I tried mentally to design a test to flush it out, but sleep overtook me. At least it's here for any future newcomers.